# iOS: Can a library in Objective C produce a pop up window and manage an interaction?

Tags: ios, static-libraries, uiwindow

I want to make a class in a library that will, upon request, do a complicated interaction with the user. The app that initializes the library will not provide any info like its UIWindow or anything. Is this technically possible? I know I can do a simple popup but what about something that needs to be constructed on the fly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIViewController` for any complex user interaction. In order to present a view controller modally, you'll have to find a suitable parent view controller.
You can get access to the app's root view controller using the `-rootViewController` method of `UIWindow` like that:

```
NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
UIViewController *rootViewController = (windows.count > 0) ? [[windows objectAtIndex:0] rootViewController] : nil;
if (rootViewController)
    // Present your view controller modally
else
    // Unable to present any view controller
```

You can also provide a delegate method and use this to get a view controller:

```
- (UIViewController *) rootViewControllerForComplexClass:(id)complexClass;
```

In your library you have access to the delegate and access the view controller like that:

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [self.delegate rootViewControllerForComplexClass:self];
// Present your view controller modally
```

Comment: I'm not using -keyWindow, because typically you only have one UIWindow, which is declared in your UIApplicationDelegate class and that is always the window at index 0 and not the topmost!

Answer (score 2):

Your library will have access to singletons like `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`, so if you want to present something to the user, you can just add your view to the window directly:

```
- (void)addViewToWindow:(UIView *)aView
{
    UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [mainWindow addSubview:aView];
}
```

Perhaps a better way would be to present it modally from within a view controller, though.

Comment: Can I create a view controller and add that to the window, and then call its method to start a modal interaction?

Comment: Yes, but if that's the route you're going, I think you should reconsider your options. Why not have users of your library present your view controller themselves with `-presentModalViewControllerAnimated:`?